# How can I place an external image of given dimensions at the center of a pgfplot?

Tags: pgfplots

Let's say I would like to place a certain picture at the center of my plot, such that it matches some given dimension on the scale of my `pgfplot`. I was thinking at first that I could include an external image in the standard procedure, with the key `axis equal image`. However, I would like to draw around the image in the middle, so that the axes need to remain scalable. I think that the latter option would thus not work.

To give you a more concrete example, I want to draw planar orbits around the Moon. To give a sense of scale, I want to draw the Moon in the middle of the plot, and then draw any kinds of orbit.

Say I want to draw a simple circular orbit of 200 km around the Moon, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rMoon}{1737.4}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rOrbit}{200}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis equal
            ]
            \addplot[samples=100, domain=0:2*pi] 
            ({(\rMoon+\rOrbit) * cos(deg(x))}, {(\rMoon+\rOrbit) * sin(deg(x))}); 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image: Orbit]

How can I place a picture of the Moon in the middle? The radius of the Moon is 1737.4 km.

You can use the following asset:

[image: Moon]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what `\addplot graphics` is for. If you add the image using

```
\addplot graphics [xmin=-\rMoon, xmax=\rMoon, ymin=-\rMoon, ymax=\rMoon] {moon.png};
```

it is automatically scaled and positioned correctly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rMoon}{1737.4}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rOrbit}{200}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis equal,
            ]
            \addplot graphics [xmin=-\rMoon, xmax=\rMoon, ymin=-\rMoon, ymax=\rMoon] {moon.png};
            \addplot[samples=100, domain=0:2*pi] 
            ({(\rMoon+\rOrbit) * cos(deg(x))}, {(\rMoon+\rOrbit) * sin(deg(x))}); 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With manually scaling with your image given in question:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots,graphicx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rMoon}{1737.4}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rOrbit}{200}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis equal
            ]
        \addplot[samples=100, domain=0:2*pi] 
            ({(\rMoon) * cos(deg(x))}, {(\rMoon) * sin(deg(x))}); 
        \node (label) at (axis cs:0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.387]{moon.png}};
        \addplot[samples=100, domain=0:2*pi] 
            ({(\rMoon+\rOrbit) * cos(deg(x))}, {(\rMoon+\rOrbit) * sin(deg(x))}); 
        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. A few remarks and questions. a) The Moon seems to be too large now. Is it really exactly sized as it should be? b) The orbit is not drawn anymore. c) Can this not be automated? That would make my life a whole lot easier, because I need to draw tons of orbits.

Comment: I could not find any scaling method relative to cs coordinate in pgfplots yet. But I will try. My scaling is fit to your `\rMoon+\rOrbit` values.

Comment: Thanks for trying around. I also gave it a shot, but until now couldn't find any way.

Comment: Now fit to `\rMoon` but it is not yet automated for scaling.